# Hiding Items of a ListBox which has Datatemplate in Codebehind WPF

Tags: wpf

I Have a listbox with DataTemplate assigned to its' ItemTemplate as below:

```
<ListBox Name="DayOverview">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Width="125" Background="Transparent" Orientation="Horizontal" MouseLeftButtonDown="DayOverview_MouseLeftButtonDown">
                <Label Content="{Binding Owner}"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding Subject}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I want to set some of its' Items Visiblity to collapse in codebehind like below:

```
(DayOverview.Items[i] as ListBoxItem).Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

but I can't convert Its' Items to ListBoxItem or any other control, Items are type of a class. Is it possible to hide Items of a ListBox with datatemplate in C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DayOverview.Items` collection will contain the items you bound the `ItemsSource` property to. It is the data not the Visual container. A `ListBox` will generate a `ListBoxItem` Container for each of your Items using `ItemContainerGenerator`.

You can get the visual Container from data item using `ItemContainerGenerator`'s ContainerFromIndex method.

Try this:

```
DayOverview.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as ListBoxItem).Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Answer (score 0):

That’s looks like a job for the [`CollectionViewSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var cvs = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(listbox.Items);
cvs.Filter = item => ((ItemType) item).Name == "Bob"; // assign a Filtermethode like this
cvs.Filter = FilterMethod; // or like this

private bool FilterMethod(object obj)
{
    var item = (ItemType) obj;
    return item.Name == "Bob";
}
```

the CollectionViewSource uses a `Predicate` with determines if an item should be shown or not.